# Backtesting.py backtest statistics only shows nans and 0

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, back-testing

I am trying to backtest a momentum strategy using Backtesting.py. I've gathered the data and computed indicator values using pandas_ta. I've defined short and long trading conditions. Now I just need Backtesting.py to run a backtest so that I can determine the performance of my strategy on historical data.

I am expecting stats from `bt.run()` to show me values instead of `nan` and 0.

I am working using this notebook: https://github.com/kbs-code/algo_trader/blob/master/backtests/backtestingdotpy_SPY_weekly_vortex.ipynb

EDIT: The name of this notebook is now https://github.com/kbs-code/algo_trader/blob/master/backtests/debugging_example_backtestingdotpy.ipynb

Thanks

Comment: I modified my code a bit to use vortex values as the only conditions for the strategy.  I made a for loop to walk through the dataframe and verify that the proper buy and sell signals are being generated.  The issue seems to stem from backtesting.py interaction with the dataframe.

Comment: I modified the trading logic so that it is only using the vortex indicator.  If I implement a buy a hold strategy with `self.close` the backtester places one trade as expected.  If I implement a simple vortex crossover instead, the backtester won't place any trades.

Comment: the very least you should do is handle NaN entries: replace or remove them from the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backtester must use "self.data.foo" and not "self.foo" in order to use values inside any column.  Please see the updated notebook with troubleshooting proof.

Answer (score 0):

In your strategy, you seem to place a buy order if your vortex-based condition is met. However, you never close the position (with `self.position.close()`). If you don't close the position, your trade will never end, which does not make room for a second trade.

To fix this, you need to either implement an exit strategy or use a take-profit (and optionally a stop-loss).

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: your premise is incorrect; a buy order was never placed in the error example, and backtesting.py doesn't require `self.close()`.  In my `BuyAndHold` example I was able to place 1 trade without `self.close()` because the position was closed automatically when the backtest ended.